# Toggle p:fieldset from another button

Tags: jsf, primefaces, fieldset

I want to expand/collapse a fieldset from buttons that are outside and inside of the fieldset, The problem is that not always the effect is the desired one. Some times the fieldset expands and collapses in a blink of an eye, sometimes it remains always open. However if a click in another button wich is not related with the fieldset, it seems that "reset" the state, and buttons starts to work fine for a while, till , for example, when the form validation fails.
Here is the whole XHTML.
I suspect this is because any AJAX issue

Thanks very much in advance

```
<p:fieldset id="fs_new_po"
            widgetVar="fs_new_po"
            legend="#{msg['btn_add_po.manage_po']}"
            toggleable="true"
            toggleSpeed="500"
            collapsed="true">
    ....

    <p:column>
        <p:commandButton process="@this"
                         update=":mng_po:fs_new_po :mng_po:msgs"
                         value="#{msg['btnCancel']}" 
                         onclick="PF('fs_new_po').toggle();"
                         actionListener="#{managePO.btnCancelClick}"/>
    </p:column>
</p:row>
</p:panelGrid>

</p:fieldset>

...

<p:commandButton process="@this"
                 update=":mng_po:fs_new_po"
                 oncomplete="PF('fs_new_po').toggle();"
                 icon="ui-icon-pencil"
                 title="edit"
                 action="#{managePO.btnEditClick}">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{po}" target="#{managePO.selectedPo}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

Comment: Too much code. Could you please isolate the suspicious portion which might be needed to show?

Comment: Edited, Sorry I thought any info could be important

Comment: Do you see some errors on the browser console?

Comment: Nope, no errors on console, thnx

Comment: Does that `<p:fieldset>` stop working only after an AJAX update made by one of those `<p:commandButton>` else it works normally? If it is that then, try updating only the container elements of that `<p:fieldset>` (by mentioning a list of components to be updated in the `update` attribute of those `<p:commandButton>`s) and avoid updating the entire `<p:fieldset>`.

Comment: Hello. If I press the embedded button of the fielset it works fine. Expands and colapses as I expect. To tell the truth I only need to expand the fieldset from the button placed outside of the fieldset, and collapse from the buttons that are placed inside of the fieldset. Anyway I`ll update just the elements inside of the fieldset and I' ll let you know. Thank you very much

Comment: Hi Tiny! it works! I update just the content that can be update an not the whole fielset. Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome absolutely! If you would like, you could post the answer and mark it. So that the question will not unnecessarily be bumping in [the unanswered question list](http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the suggestion of Tiny, I update onclick event just the content of the fieldset that could be change.

```
<p:fieldset id="fs_new_po"
        widgetVar="fs_new_po"
        legend="#{msg['btn_add_po.manage_po']}"
        toggleable="true"
        toggleSpeed="500"
        collapsed="true">
   //ADDED A CONTENT INSIDE THE FIELDSET TO BE UPDATED
   <p:panelGrid id="fs_cntnt">

....

   <p:column>
       //UPDATE JUST THE CONTENT OF THE FIELDSET
       <p:commandButton process="@this" update=":mng_po:fs_cntnt :mng_po:msgs" value="#   {msg['btnCancel']}" onclick="PF('fs_new_po').toggle();" actionListener="#{managePO.btnCancelClick}" />
   </p:column>
</p:row>
</p:panelGrid>

</p:fieldset>

...
 //UPDATE JUST THE CONTENT OF THE FIELDSET
<p:commandButton process="@this" update=":mng_po:fs_cntnt"  oncomplete="PF('fs_new_po').toggle();" icon="ui-icon-pencil" title="edit" action="#{managePO.btnEditClick}" >
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{po}" target="#{managePO.selectedPo}" />
                </p:commandButton>
```

Thank you Tiny!